# Extract substrings from pandas rows that starts and ends with a special character

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have this df:

```
id  description
0   changed status to **In progress** of this task
1   changed status to **Closed** of this task   
2   changed status to **Testing** of this task
3   changed status to **Update** of this task
4   changed status to **Completed** of this task
```

I want to subset this df by extracting the substring from the description column that are between `**` such as `In Progress`, `Closed`, `Testing`, `Update` and `Completed`.

I tried regex by following some stack overflow's solutions such as:

```
import re
re.search('**(.+?)**', df.description)
```

But I got this error:

```
error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has regex imbedded:

```
>>> df['description'].str.extract('\*\*(.*)\*\*')
             0
0  In progress
1       Closed
2      Testing
3       Update
4    Completed
>>>
```

Just use the `str.extract` method.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a Series to `re.search`. It expects a single string. Use the `str.extract` pandas method instead:

```
df.description.str.extract(r'\*\*(.+?)\*\*')
```

Comment: Yeah! `str.extract` is handy here, same idea as like in my answer! :P

Comment: Sorry, cross-posting ;)

Comment: It's fine :P our expressions are a bit different

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk is a special character in regex.  If you want a literal asterisk, you need to escape it with a `\`.

```
import re
re.search('\*\*(.+?)\*\*', df.description)
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the error. `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`